# docker-compose inter container communication

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I'm currently experimenting with Spring Boot-based microservices and getting to grips with docker, but I'm hitting a snag.

Basically what I'm trying to do is containerize 2 small services: a spring cloud config service and a spring cloud eureka service (discovery service). The eureka service fetches its configuration from the config service.

Both services are separate projects with their own Dockerfiles:

**Dockerfile-cloud-config-service:**

```
FROM openjdk:10.0.2-13-jre-sid
ENV APP_FILE cloud-config-service.jar
ENV APP_HOME /usr/apps
EXPOSE 8888
COPY target/$APP_FILE $APP_HOME/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["exec java -jar $APP_FILE"]
```

**Dockerfile-discovery-service:**

```
FROM openjdk:10.0.2-13-jre-sid
ENV APP_FILE discovery-service.jar
ENV APP_HOME /usr/apps
EXPOSE 8761
COPY target/$APP_FILE $APP_HOME/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["exec java -jar $APP_FILE"]
```

Using docker-compose I'm trying to tie them together using the following **docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  cloud-config-service:
    container_name: cloud-config-service
    build:
      context: cloud-config-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-cloud-config-service
    image: cloud-config-service:latest
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    networks:
      - emp-network

  discovery-service:
    container_name: discovery-service
    build:
      context: discovery-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-discovery-service
    image: discovery-service:latest
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    networks:
      - emp-network
    links:
      - cloud-config-service

networks:
  emp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

At first I configured the discovery-service to fetch its configuration from *http://localhost:8888*, but after some digging I found that localhost in a container refers to the container itself and found in the Docker documentation that services can refer to each other using their names. So I changed discovery-service's properties to fetch its config from *http://cloud-config-service:8888*. That doesn't work, hence this post.

Both Dockerfiles build and run just fine, except the fact that the discovery-service fails to GET the config-service on *http://cloud-config-service:8888*.

It does work if I use the `host` network driver and the *http://localhost:8888* endpoint, but this 'feels' hacky and not how it is supposed to be done.

I'm probably missing something trivial, but I'm afraid I can't find what.

**EDIT:**
Small snippet of discovery-service's console log:

```
discovery-service       | 2018-10-02 13:14:26.798  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://cloud-config-service:8888
cloud-config-service    | 2018-10-02 13:14:26.836  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8a18e3b3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
discovery-service       | 2018-10-02 13:14:27.129  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://cloud-config-service:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
discovery-service       | 2018-10-02 13:14:27.129  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://cloud-config-service:8888/discovery-service/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, communication between docker containers is a subset of a much bigger problem prevalent in distributed services - You don't know what service (and hence [their dependencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_failure)) will go down at any moment, and so you should take into account such failures when you build your application.

The problem that you are facing is common, even more so with Docker containers, and I believe inter-container communication is a major piece in Docker that is under frequent development changes.

To address your problem, first, I would like to put forth some points -

1. `localhost` from within a container will refer to that container itself.
2. `localhost` on your machine does in fact refer to your local host and will be mapped with services you map through the `ports` configuration for each of your services in the `docker-compose` file.
3. `depends_on` only waits for the container to start and not for the actual process to start running - which might mean that the service you are waiting for isn't necessarily up and running yet, and so, cause timeouts for the dependent service(s).

What you need is to wait for the service to start running, not just the container to be up. There are two possible ways you can accomplish this -

1. Specify a `restart` policy for your `discovery-service` based on failure. In your case, failure would be when it times out while connecting to the `cloud-config-service`. Something like `restart: on-failure:10` which means you are asking docker to restart the `discover-service` when it fails with a maximum retry of 10. That way, you would have given reasonable time for the other container (service) to be up and running and make sure that the container with the restart policy *eventually* connects to that one.
2. Use another tool like [dockerize](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize) that allows you to [wait](https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize#waiting-for-other-dependencies) on other services before starting up the container.

Also, to make sure you are debugging the problem correctly, be sure to check the logs of your container to see what the issue really is - `docker logs -f --tail=100 <container_name/container_id>`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will take a deeper dive into startup and dependency order. The strange thing is: doing a `docker exec curl` as suggested by @Niradnik actually returns the correct configuration. I'm beginning to think the problem lies somewhere in the way Spring Cloud queries the address specified in the properties file.

Comment: I have been struggling with a similar issue. Communication between MySQL and Spring Boot containers through docker-compose. Solution #1 (restart: on-failure:10) worked for me. Thank you @graveti.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment so I'm writing a new answer.

did you try to run something like `docker exec -it myconatiner1 curl myconatiner2:port`

to see if it sees it or a ping and if not what is the error?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As it turns out, curling the configuration-service actually works! I'm now beginning to think that the issue lies somewhere with the way Spring Cloud queries the address specified in the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are on right track ... I would introduce notion of `depends_on` to tell container `discovery-service` to wait on the booting up of container `cloud-config-service` before it boots up

```
  discovery-service:
    container_name: discovery-service
    build:
      context: discovery-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-discovery-service
    image: discovery-service:latest
    depends_on:
      - cloud-config-service
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    networks:
      - emp-network
    links:
      - cloud-config-service
```

there is a finite period of time required to boot up a container before it can actively handle traffic so its good to attend to this launch sequence, especially true when dealing with say a database container, which others should `depends_on`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @scott-stensland. Unfortunately that wasn't it. Originally I did have a `depends-on` in docker-compose.yml until I came across the following passage in the Docker Compose docs on `links`: "Links also express dependency between services in the same way as depends_on, so they determine the order of service startup."

Comment: next I would eliminate mention of networks ... by default it will spin up a bridge network

Comment: removed networks and every mention of it from .yml, but unfortunately to no avail.